# Using MySQL query with multiple OR clauses

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I didn't find any thing that could help me solve this:

```
$hvorerjeg = $db->query("SELECT * 
    FROM `ts` 
    WHERE `aktiv` = '1' 
      AND `player1` = '$obj->id' 
      OR `player2` = '$obj->id' 
      OR `player3` = '$obj->id' 
      OR `player4` = '$obj->id'"); 
//Checks if user is player1 or player2 or player3 or player4
```

The code I want to check if the users is player1, player2, player3 or player4, but this doesn't work for me.

I've looked for the answer but I can't solve it. I'm very new to PHP.

Comment: are you sure that you have 4 columns in your table? `player1, player2, player3, player4` ? really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL the AND operator has precedence over the OR operator.

```
$hvorerjeg = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `ts` WHERE `aktiv` = '1'
  AND (
  `player1` = '$obj->id' OR
  `player2` = '$obj->id' OR
  `player3` = '$obj->id' OR
  `player4` = '$obj->id')
");
```

As a side note, this code is vulnerable to sql injection. Use prepared statements instead to make your code safer.

Comment: Your group of parenthesis are encapsulating the end double quotation mark for the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping the ORs since if 1 returns true their group will return true.

```
$hvorerjeg = $db->query(
    "SELECT * FROM `ts` WHERE 
    `aktiv` = '1' AND 
    (
        `player1` = '$obj->id' OR 
        `player2` = '$obj->id' OR 
        `player3` = '$obj->id' OR 
        `player4` = '$obj->id'
    )"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$hvorerjeg = $db->query("SELECT * 
    FROM `ts` 
    WHERE aktiv = '1' 
    AND (player1 = '" .  $obj->id . "'" . 
         " OR player2 = '" . $obj->id . "'" . 
         " OR player3 = '" . $obj->id . "'" . 
         " OR player4 = '" . $obj->id . "')");
```

Comment: you're from a C++ / JS background?

Comment: tell me, what are the `+`'s supposed to do, math?

Comment: Sorry, I am working with python in a project and sometimes I got a salad of languages in my head.